# What is difference between executable and install able jars

Tags: java, jar, installation, launch4j

I am developing one desktop application in javaFX. I am using in memory database hsqldb. I want to make this application to run on any windows machine by just double click or by installing.

I have gone through the launch4j library, using which I can make .exe file of my jar.

But if I create the .exe file, then I can open this application by just double clicking on it. anyone can copy and paste and open it.

I am confused with install word here.

`What extra things will happens`, if I want to make my application installable. Because I want to give an expiry date my application.

Comment: if you want a .exe file, why did you write your code in Java? even if you decide to make it a .exe, everything can be decompiled (if the user knows what he's doing).

the only 'certain' way to achieve something like that, is to run the actual business logic on a server you control, and not distributing the code. then you can perform the 'check number of days remaining' away from the users influence.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies on the description of launch4j on their site.

> The executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version
>   or use a bundled one, and it's possible to set runtime options, like
>   the initial/max heap size

Not every machine you distribute the jar to may have a `JRE`. A bundled `JRE` will help the launcher run your jar if a `JRE` cannot be found on the target machine.

If you want to force updates on your jar, consider running a plugin mechanism or forcing the user to download a new version. It sounds to me like a web application might suffice instead ?